# NB-IoT signal quality query (operator independent)

Tags: quectel, nb-iot

I'm currently developing an `NB-IoT` application using `Quectel's BC66`, however, I'm still trying to decide what operator to use.

After a successful connection, I can use the command `AT+CSQ` or `AT+CESQ` to find signal quality.
But all this is assuming I have an operator X SIM card.

After the `NPSS/NSSS` block up to the PDNConnectionRequest, we have at least 9 transactions between the UE and eNB according to [this](http://www.codeplayon.com/2019/03/narrow-band-iot-ue-attach-call-flow-messaging-2/).

During all these transactions, an operator is still not decided, is it possible to check signal quality at this stage? The alternative would be to have 3 SIM cards and test the connection with each one, one at a time. (We have 3 operators with `NB-IoT` service available)

I've been searching for this everywhere with no results yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking Quectel, found out this is not possible.
To check signal quality you need a valid connection with the operator.

Either we have a SIM card from each operator and check signal quality using those or we need a SIM card that supports multi-operator (didn't even knew those existed)